# How to build a Hover in css and html, where an image appears while hovering over a colored background?

Tags: css, html, hover

I don't know how to fix this Problem. The case is that i want to build a hover where there first is just a colored box (div or however) with a keyword written in in it e.g. "our burger" and if you actually hover it an image appears instead of the colored background of the box and the text is still there... I yet can't still figure out how to code it and if there is a solution without js?!

Answer (score 1):

you can give class to div and can style it in css like

```css
.hello:hover {
  background-image:url("image url here");
}
```

```html
<div class="hello">Content here</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div>Keyword</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  background: #999;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

div:hover {
  background-image: url('http://rs267.pbsrc.com/albums/ii282/paullasue/ATT859028.gif~c200');
}
```

Try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/qgd83cw3/

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to achieve this would be adding a bit of `JavaScript` to the `div`:

```js
onmouseover="document.getElementById('textid').style.display = 'none';"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

HTML:

```
<div id="Insert_here">Name
<div id="Image">Name //Or whatever you call it.
```

CSS:

```
    #Insert_here #Image{display:none;}
    #Insert_here:hover #Image{display:inline-block; visibility:visible;}
//This turns makes the image appear after you hover over the text/coloured box
```